# School Scheduling (Constrained Logic)

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to build a school scheduling program in prolog. I want to check if a teacher is available at a given time to teach a certain this class; check allowable time slots; etc.

Here's what I've been able to write so far:

```
teacher(ali, bio).
teacher(sara, math).
teacher(john, lit).
teacher(milton, arabic).

% a, b, c, d, e, f, g
timeslot(a).
timeslot(b).

% class has a name and a grade
class(bio, 1).
class(math, 1).
class(lit, 2).
class(arabic, 2).
```

How do I establish that a class cannot have two timeslots?

I have used a little bit of Prolog, but I'm not sure how to go about this. Any further tips and indications, like papers or similar problems that are solved more frequently, would be appreciated.

Comment: Build a small example with two teacher, and three or four schedule entries; then define a couple of truths, and build statements that hold true given sets of conditions. After that, post what you came up with, and others will be glad to help you in whatever you may get stuck at.

Comment: Thanks! I just added more details!

Comment: Please give an example of what you want the output to be. What is the relevance of the grade and the timeslot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wrote two years ago a scheduling program for assessment center and used clpfd for that because in normal swi-prolog it would be much more complicated and the problem is scaling exponentional with the complexity so if you have a real school with lots of teachers, lessions etc this will be not really efficient without constraint programming.

Please have a look int clp(fd) at [swi-prolog website](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html)

Kind regards

solick

Answer (score 4):

The wording of the Question suggests that a program is to be written that will produce (or at least check) a proposed class schedule.

Inputs to the program appear to be a list of teachers (and their subjects), a list of time slots, and a list of classes (and their subjects/grades).

Presumably there are several "cardinality" restrictions (sometimes called "business rules") that a proper class schedule must meet.  A class can only be given once (not two time slots) is the point of the Question, but also a teacher can only teach one class per time slot, etc.

How can these restrictions be indicated?  Prolog predicates do not have inherent restrictions of this kind, but they can be implemented either structurally or logically (i.e. in the program's logical checking).

An example of doing things in a structural way would be adding a field to the `class` predicate to represent the assigned timeslot.  Some logic would be involved in how this field is assigned, to insure that value is a valid time slot.

An example of doing the relationship between classes and time slots in a logical fashion would be to define an additional predicate that models the assignment of time slots to classes (presumably something similar applies to assigning classes to teachers).  You would have, as illustration, predicate `class_timeslot(Class,Timeslot)`.  The rules of your program would enforce the uniqueness of one instance of these (dynamically asserted) *facts* per `Class` instance, and the validity of the `Timeslot` value.

Alternatively, instead of dynamic facts, the class schedule could be constructed as a list of structures similarly pairing classes and time slots.  But the point is that program logic needs to implement that this pairing is a functional relationship.